# React Native - How to append to parent state array while in child component (StackNavigators)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child, react-navigation

My project is looping through a data array in a child component `Main`, and I'm trying to update the state in parent component, `App`, on an event (swiping right on a card in `Main`), so that I could access the data that was 'swiped right' on a sibling Component in `Favorites`. Hopefully that makes sense?

The project structure is as such:

```
App
 |__ Rootstack
       |
       |__Favorites
       |__Main
```

In my `Main` component, I am mapping the `collection` array and looping thru:

```
collection = imagedata;
// a local JSON array of data that I am looping thru in Main

class Main extends React.Component {
  _toFavs = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Favorites');
  };

  render() {
      const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <Card key={index}>
              ......
            </Card>
        )
      });

      return (
      <View>

            <CardStack
             onSwiped={() => {console.log('onSwiped')}
             onSwipedRight={() => console.log('onSwipedLeft')}>
             //
             //HERE IS THE PART - HOW TO UPDATE THE 'favoritesList' array in the parent 'App's state?
             //
              {contents}

            </CardStack>

      </View>
        );
    }
}

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: Main},
    Favorites: {
      screen: Favorites}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
  }
);

class Favorites extends React.Component {
 // The plan is to eventually access the favoritesList array in App's state here and display cards that were swiped right in the Main component.
  _onPress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
    };
  render() {
    return (
        <View><Text>Hello!</Text></View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        favoritesList: []
      };
    }
  render() {
      return <RootStack />;
    }
  }
```

I've come across some other answers of updating state such as 
`this.setState({ favoritesList: [...this.state.favoritesList, 'new value'] })`, but how can I do this to the .state of `App` while i'm inside a child component `Main`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an ideal use case for Redux and it's connect function.

Comment: you can use redux  or pass function as props from 
 App >> Rootstack >> Main

Comment: @Man Could you elaborate on how to pass a function down as props from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

```
        collection = imagedata;
    // a local JSON array of data that I am looping thru in Main

    class Main extends React.Component {
      _toFavs = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Favorites');
      };

      render() {
          const contents = collection.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Card key={index}>
                  ......
                </Card>
            )
          });

          return (
          <View>

                <CardStack
                 onSwiped={() => {console.log('onSwiped')}
                 onSwipedRight={() => {console.log('onSwipedLeft') ;
                                 this.props.screenProps()}}>
                 //

                  {contents}

                </CardStack>

          </View>
            );
        }
    }

    const RootStack = StackNavigator(
      {
        Main: {
          screen: Main},
        Favorites: {
          screen: Favorites}
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Main'
      }
    );

    class Favorites extends React.Component {
     // The plan is to eventually access the favoritesList array in App's state here and display cards that were swiped right in the Main component.
      _onPress = () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        };
      render() {
        return (
            <View><Text>Hello!</Text></View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default class App extends Component<{}> {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            favoritesList: []
          };
        }
     updateArr=()=>{consol.log("fire")  }

      render() {
          return <RootStack  screenProps={this.updateArr} />;
        }
      }
```

i hope it solve your problem

update props-name

Comment: thanks for the reply Man -- does this work for you though? to just test out passing function as props I tried with `updateArr=()=>{console.log('updateArr')};` and then passing it as a prop to RootStack `return <RootStack updateArray={this.updateArr} />;` and then calling that prop function within App as such `onSwiped={() => {console.log('onSwiped'),
                              this.props.updateArray}}` but I'm getting no console log message of 'updateArr' ('onSwiped' logs successfully). Is there anything I'm forgetting? Is 'binding' something I have to do?

Comment: or if i do `return <RootStack updateArray={this.updateArr()} />;` and `onSwiped={() => {console.log('onSwiped'),
                              this.props.updateArray()}}`, I do get the 'updateArr' consolelog message but then an error that `_this4.props.updateArray is not a function`.

Comment: this is not this4.props.updateArray() , type correct spelling this.props.updateAaray() ,   else before call check all props in componentwillmount()

Comment: sorry Man -- thanks for your help but I don't understand your latest comment. `_this4.props.updateArray is not a function` is the error i get.